# ambari unable add metric widgets

Tags: javascript, python, ambari

I wrote a component for ambari and the metrics widgets.However i can't add the widgets for this component. I think i need some help...

my ambari version is 2.5.2 and i check the web problem.
when i open the page of this component page, it shows as

```
app.js:66933 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'WidgetLayoutInfo' of undefined
    at Class.createUserWidgetLayout (app.js:66933)
    at Class.<anonymous> (app.js:66874)
    at o (vendor.js:125)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (vendor.js:125)
    at w (vendor.js:127)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (vendor.js:127)
```

when i try to add widget.it shows as

```
app.js:26574 Uncaught TypeError: activeLayout.get is not a function
    at Class.addWidget (app.js:26574)
    at handler (vendor.js:21227)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (vendor.js:13019)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (vendor.js:126)
    at HTMLDivElement.i (vendor.js:126)
```

finaly i try to create a widgets, the console shows as

```
app.js:85210 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mapProperty' of undefined
    at Class.createServiceWidget (app.js:85210)
    at Class.sendRecursively (vendor.js:17348)
    at Class.sendRecursively (vendor.js:17352)
    at Class.sendRecursively (vendor.js:17352)
    at Class.sendRecursively (vendor.js:17352)
    at Class.send (vendor.js:17333)
    at Class.createWidget (app.js:26730)
    at Class.createWidget (app.js:26849)
    at handler (vendor.js:21227)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (vendor.js:13019)
```

this is my metainfo.xml

```xml
<metainfo>
    <schemaVersion>2.0</schemaVersion>
    <services>
        <service>
            <name>REDISCLUSTER</name>
            <displayName>Redis Cluster</displayName>
            <comment>the component of redis cluster</comment>
            <version>4.0.8</version>
            <components>
                <component>
                    <name>REDIS_SERVER</name>
                    <displayName>redis server</displayName>
                    <category>MASTER</category>
                    <cardinality>1+</cardinality>
                    <timelineAppid>rediscluster</timelineAppid>
                    <commandScript>
                        <script>scripts/server.py</script>
                        <scriptType>PYTHON</scriptType>
                        <timeout>600</timeout>
                    </commandScript>
                </component>
            </components>
            <osSpecifics>
                <osSpecific>
                    <osFamily>any</osFamily>
                </osSpecific>
            </osSpecifics>
        </service>
    </services>
</metainfo>
```

this is the metrics.json

```
{
    "REDIS_SERVER": {
        "Component": [
            {
                "type": "ganglia",
                "metrics": {
                    "default": {

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_used_memory": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_used_memory",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_maxmemory": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_maxmemory",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_used_memory_rss": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_used_memory_rss",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_used_memory_peak": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_used_memory_peak",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_mem_fragmentation_ratio": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_mem_fragmentation_ratio",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_instantaneous_input_kbps": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_input_kbps",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_instantaneous_output_kbps": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_output_kbps",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_rejected_connections": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_rejected_connections",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_keyspace_hits": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_keyspace_hits",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_keyspace_misses": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_keyspace_misses",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        },

                        "metrics/redis_cluster_used_cpu_sys": {
                            "metric": "redis_cluster_used_cpu_sys",
                            "pointInTime": true,
                            "temporal": true
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this is the widgets.json

```
{
    "layouts": [
        {
            "layout_name": "default_redis_cluster_dashboard",
            "display_name": "Standard Redis Cluster Dashboard",
            "section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
            "widgetLayoutInfo": [
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_used_memory",
                    "description": "Redis used memory widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_memory",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_used_memory",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_memory",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_used_memory}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_maxmemory",
                    "description": "Redis maxmemory widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_maxmemory",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_maxmemory",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_maxmemory",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_maxmemory}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_used_memory_rss",
                    "description": "Redis used_memory_rss widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_memory_rss",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_used_memory_rss",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_memory_rss",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_used_memory_rss}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_used_memory_peak",
                    "description": "Redis used_memory_peak widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_memory_peak",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_used_memory_peak",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_memory_peak",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_used_memory_peak}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_mem_fragmentation_ratio",
                    "description": "Redis mem_fragmentation_ratio widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_mem_fragmentation_ratio",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_mem_fragmentation_ratio",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_mem_fragmentation_ratio",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_mem_fragmentation_ratio}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_input_kbps",
                    "description": "Redis instantaneous_input_kbps widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_input_kbps",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_instantaneous_input_kbps",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_input_kbps",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_instantaneous_input_kbps}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_output_kbps",
                    "description": "Redis instantaneous_output_kbps widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_output_kbps",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_instantaneous_output_kbps",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_instantaneous_output_kbps",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_instantaneous_output_kbps}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_rejected_connections",
                    "description": "Redis rejected_connections widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_rejected_connections",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_rejected_connections",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_rejected_connections",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_rejected_connections}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_keyspace_hits",
                    "description": "Redis keyspace_hits widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_keyspace_hits",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_keyspace_hits",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_keyspace_hits",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_keyspace_hits}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_keyspace_misses",
                    "description": "Redis keyspace_misses widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_keyspace_misses",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_keyspace_misses",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_keyspace_misses",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_keyspace_misses}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "widget_name": "redis_cluster_used_cpu_sys",
                    "description": "Redis used_cpu_sys widget",
                    "default_section_name": "REDISCLUSTER_SUMMARY",
                    "widget_type": "GRAPH",
                    "is_visible": true,
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_cpu_sys",
                            "metric_path": "metrics/redis_cluster_used_cpu_sys",
                            "service_name": "REDISCLUSTER",
                            "component_name": "REDIS_SERVER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "redis_cluster_used_cpu_sys",
                            "value": "${redis_cluster_used_cpu_sys}"
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "graph_type": "LINE",
                        "time_range": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Facing same issue, Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the ambari-server exception.

> Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'active_widget_layouts' at row 1
> Error Code: 1406
> Call: UPDATE users SET active_widget_layouts = ?, version = ? WHERE ((user_id = ?) AND (version = ?))

> alter table users modify column active_widget_layouts varchar(2048);

[my ambari-server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Yz9.png)